# How to get access to a column in a 2D list in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using a 2D list, and I'd like to calculate its mean value by row. The following is my code:

```
import numpy as np

mylist = np.zeros((2,120))    # This gives you a 2 by 120 2D list with 2 rows, and 120 columns
average_list = np.zeros(120)

for col in xrange(120):
    average_list[col] = np.mean(mylist[:][col])
```

However, the above chunk generates this:

> IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

As I find during debugging, the problem happens at the `col` in `np.mean(mylist[:][col])`

May I know what am I wrong about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a column in a list of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360162/how-to-access-a-column-in-a-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to fix your code (with minimal changes) would be

```
for col in xrange(120):
    average_array[col] = np.mean(myarray[:, col])
```

However, a better way would be to avoid the `for-loop` and use `axis=0`:

```
average_array = myarray.mean(axis=0)   # 1
```

`axis=0`  tells `mean` to take the mean over the first axis, i.e.
    the rows.

---

A small example may help you see the difference between `myarray[:][col]` and `myarray[:, col]`:

```
In [7]: myarray = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

In [8]: myarray
Out[8]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])

In [9]: myarray[:][0]
Out[9]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [10]: myarray[:, 0]
Out[10]: array([0, 3])
```

As you can see `myarray[:][0]` selects the 0th **row** of a (copy of) `myarray`. So `myarray[:][col]` raises an IndexError when `col` is greater than 1, since there are only 2 rows.

Answer (score 1):

`mylist` has 2 lists in it. So index 2 is out of bounds.

```
>>> mylist
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: When I say `np.mean(mylist[:][col])`, I think I am visiting the `col`th element across all lists in the 2D list. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks. :)

Comment: `mylist[:][col]` means make a copy of mylist and get the `col`-th item. but mylist has just 2 items, 2 lists. So index 2 is out of bounds

Answer (score 1):

When you do `mylist[:]` you making a copy of the 2D array and then with `mylist[:][col]` you are indexing the first dimension. Try this:

```
for col in xrange(120):
    average_list[col] = np.mean([ x[col] for x in mylist] )
```

But [unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21855389/390913) is far more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly an answer to your question, but you can specify an axis to calculate the mean on:

```
np.mean(mylist, axis=0)
```

`axis=0` will give you row-wise mean, whereas `axis=1` will give you the column-wise mean.