# Looping of python list,whose elements are also a list

Tags: python, list

I have list, its elements are also a list.
eg:

```
outlier=[[20,2,67], [90,6,12], [23,16,7]].
```

how I write a single line code to loop `outlier` list by taking elements from same index.I want to store the looping result as a list.

Comment: Did you try yourself? post your code please.

Comment: a sample example would be good to know

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a column in a list of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360162/how-to-access-a-column-in-a-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to loop over the indices of each sublist in turn, i.e. (20, 90, 23) in the 1st loop, (2, 6, 16) in the 2nd and (67, 12, 7) in the 3rd. If this is indeed what you mean, try looking into the built-in `zip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clear to me, but if you want to make a new list that contains the first element of each list you have, then this is an example to take first element(x[0]) from each list and store them in a new list called "new_list":

`new_list = [x[0] for x in outlier]`