# Getting TypeError: list indices must be integers when using list[:,colIndex] to get column data as list

Tags: jython-2.7

I have a 2D list (a list of lists) and am trying to use the notation `list[:,colIndex]` to pull out a single column's data into another list, but I'm getting a `TypeError: list indices must be integers` error.

for example:

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[10,12,13]]
lst[:,0]
```

Returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers
```

I don't understand...

Edit:
Running this in Python 3.9 gives me:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the `[:,colIndex]` syntax isn't supported by lists and is available to numpy arrays only :(

However I can use: `list(zip(*lst))[colIndex]` instead from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44360278/1733467